# How to reverse first and last name?

Tags: python

Using an input to prompt the user, how can I reverse the first and last names, capitalize the first letter and add a comma without using a compound condition? I was able to reverse it and add a comma. The problem is I don't want that last comma.

```
names=input('What is your name:').split()

for names in reversed(names):
    print(names.capitalize + ',', end=' ')
```

Result is this:

```
What is your name:steve smith

Smith, Steve,
```

Comment: can you share your coding attempt at this problem? @GMoney

Comment: `print(", ".join(n.capitalize() for n in reversed(names.split())))`

Comment: Can you describe (in words) the logic to be used to decide whether or not to print the comma? Now can you implement that in code?

Comment: If the User input is _David Lee Roth_, do you want the output to be _"Roth, Lee, David"_ or _"Roth, David Lee"_?  (Or, I suppose, _"Lee Roth, David"_)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I found the linked duplicate by putting `python print with commas between but not last` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+print+with+commas+between+but+not+last), as the first result. It is a good idea to try to [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) problems before asking here.

Comment: Thanks guys, I understand what you did. I am still learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:

```py
names = input("What is your name: ").split(" ")
print(', '.join([names[1].capitalize(), names[0].capitalize()]))
```

Comment: Just a followup, what you're looking for is explicitly the `join()` function, which glues together all the elements of an array using the joining string provided. In this case `', '`. The connecting string is only between elements, not just at the end of each element. Thus, you won't get the trailing comma.

Comment: Well, that only handles those with two names.  `', '.join(reversed(names))` might be better.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information Nathaniel. And yes Tim, you're right, I just took the example input. That was a bit short. Thanks for pointing out.